# Problem while npm install and creating react project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

I face an error while creating a react project. How I resolve it?

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-10T19_31_59_499Z-debug-0.log
```